# How do I get the text present in a particular <div> among all div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's consider following situation:

```
<div class="op">
    <input type="hidden" class="sop" value="good" name="wish"/>
    <p class="op1">good morning</p>
    <p class="frwd">forward</p>
</div>

<div class="op">
    <input type="hidden" class="sop" value="bad" name="wish"/>
    <p class="op1">bad morning</p>
    <p class="frwd">forward</p>
</div>

<div class="op">
    <input type="hidden" class="sop" value="luck" name="wish"/>
    <p class="op1">lucky morning</p>
    <p class="frwd">forward</p>
</div>
```

Now when a user clicks on **forward** then the text present in `p.op1` and value of `.sop` of that `div.op` should be retrieved.

I have tried using `$('.op1').text`, but it is giving the same value for all clicks on **forward**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".frwd").bind("click",function(){

alert($(this).parent().find(".op1").text());
alert($(this).parent().find(".sop").val());
});
})
```

Please check the below fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9QPZ8/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                     $(document).ready(function () {
                         $('.frwd').click(function () {

                             var opttext = $(this).parent().find('.op1').text();
                             alert(opttext);

                             var inputval = $(this).parent().find('.sop').val();
                             alert(inputval);

                         });

                     });

                 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('.frwd' , 'click' ,function(){
$(this).parent().find('.op1').text();
})
```

Comment: Please add a little bit of explanation of exactly what your code does. Maybe then I would think of upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".frwd").on("click",function(e){
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
          var op1text = $(this).siblings(".op1").text();
          var soptext = $(this).siblings(".sop").val();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".frwd").click(function(){
    var op1text = $(this).siblings(".op1").text();
    var soptext = $(this).siblings(".sop").val();
    alert("op1text:" + op1text);
    alert("soptext:" + soptext);

   });
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used jquery **siblings** to achieve your requirement.
For working example [**FIddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/9QPZ8/2/).

**CODE :**

```
$(".frwd").on("click",function(){
   alert($(this).siblings(".op1").text());
   alert($(this).siblings(".sop").val());
});
```